# Saving OAuth2 access tokens for sessionless authentication

Tags: javascript, session, oauth, oauth-2.0

I set up a sessionless app that uses OAuth2 password grant authentication. When a user logs into my app with a username and password I save the access token in [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) which is valid for 30 minutes. I also save a refresh token in [sessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) in case I need to extend the session longer than 30 minutes. The refresh token is valid for 30 days.

If the 'remember me' checkbox is selected on login I save the access and refresh tokens in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) so they will persist as long as the refresh token is valid.

Both of these seem to work fine except for **a couple of issues**:

1. If the browser is left open and the user doesn't log out the session could potentially last for 30 days.
2. [sessionsStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) doesn't persist between windows/tabs so if the user opens a new window they need to log in again. This is not an issue when the 'remember me' checkbox is selected since [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/LocalStorage) does persist between windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think using refresh tokens is not safe for JavaScript applications - you need to access the `/token` endpoint and authenticate using the application's secret. But the secret gets public in such applications.

I would prefer the OAuth2 implicit flow and getting new token from the `/auth` endpoint with `prompt=none` parameter (from OpenID Connect). But with the implicit flow, you would either need to get a longer living ID token (and ask for an access token with the ID token later) or to implement the "remember me" at the OAuth2 (better option - can be used by any application). That would also solve the problem #2 with passing tokens between tabs.

1. By the "session" you mean using the refresh token to generate access tokens for 30 days? If that's a problem, you can implement some activity detector which would log the user out if there is no activity for e.g. 30 minutes.
2. It's possible to use the `localStorage` as a kind of message passing service, so you can keep the tokens in the `sessionStorage`, but a new tab can use the `localStorage` to request the token from existing tabs. For more info see http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/sharing-messages-and-data-across-windows-using-localstorage/

Code example from the linked article:

```
function eventListener(e) {
    if (e.key == 'storage-event') {
        output.innerHTML = e.newValue;
    }
}

function triggerEvent() {
    localStorage.setItem('storage-event', this.value);
}

window.addEventListener("storage", eventListener, true);
data.addEventListener("keyup", triggerEvent, true);
```

The workflow would be like this:

1. New tab is opened and writes an arbitrary value to the localStorage with a key indicating that it needs a token. The key can be "newTabOpened". The new tab starts listening to changes of another key "oauth2token".
2. The existing tab listens to the changes of the "newTabOpened" key and as a reaction, it writes its token value under the "oauth2token" key.
3. The new tab reads the token and removes it from the localStorage.

Comment: I thought about using localStorage to pass the tokens between windows but that could lead to unintentionally leaving access/refresh tokens in localStorage.

Comment: The new tab can remove the tokens from the `localStorage` right after reading them.

Comment: Right, but the issue is that you'd have to place them in localStorage in anticipation for a new tab being opened. But if a new tab is never opened then there they'll sit.

Comment: I added a list of localStorage operation steps to the answer.